# How to Facebook login with registration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I am new in Ruby on Rails And i am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12

I want to user login registration with face book.

I am using omniauth for facebook login.

if i am login as facebook user the facebook given error

**Error**

**App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.**

i have create tow app also in facebook.

**Fitst App**

And Follow the rules:-

Domain name : localhost

Choose website section:

Site Url: localhost:3000/ with http

**Second App**

And Follow the rules:-

Domain name : demo.com

Choose website section:

Site Url: demo.com:3000/ with http

**Note:**

I have change my host name locahost to demo.com

My local site working fine with localhost:3000/ and demo.com:3000/

facebook given same error in every App

**Error**

**App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.**

please help

Comment: Have you disabled sandbox mode …?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when the app is still in sandbox mode and the Facebook user trying to log in has not been given authorisation to use the app.  In the app admin page on Facebook, make sure that the user trying to log in is listed on the Roles page/tab as an admin or developer or tester.  Alternatively, if you want anyone to be able to log in, turn off sandbox mode (make it "available to the general public" on the "Status and Review" page in app admin on Facebook).

Also, double-check those urls!  By the way, when you say "demo.com:3000/ with http" I assume you mean the url is "http://demo.com:3000/"?

I set up things so that I have a single Facebook app set up for a rails app, with a single domain under "App Domains" e.g. `mydomain.com`.  Then I have live/staging servers like `www.mydomain.com` and `staging.mydomain.com` and on my local machine I have `dev.mydomain.com` as an alias for localhost.  Note that I don't bother defining separate Websites for each of my subdomains for the App; I just have the production URL listed.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and this helped. Wish I were the OP so I could check it!

Comment: Glad it helped!  By the way, a few weeks ago Facebook introduced "Test Apps", so at some point I intend to switch over to separate test apps for staging/dev instead of my approach above.  Here's the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps - it looks like there are a few rough edges they'll smooth out according to the FAQs there, but it looks good, and it should be a nice way to try out different app settings in staging/dev without affecting production (and without having to maintain completely separate 'real' apps for staging/dev).